# How to use reduce function in a nested state object in reactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

My state value is

```
this.state = {
    content: {
        text: {
            tag1: {
                line: "data1"
            }
            tag2: {
                line: "data2"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How can I use javascript `reduce()` function to change the value of `line` of both `tag1` and `tag2` to `"changed text"`?

Comment: Why would you use `.reduce()` to do that?

Comment: `.reduce` is not suitable for that purpose for a whole lot of reasons, where the first one is that it's goal is to **reduce** an initial item and meant to work on **arrays**, while you need to alter an **object** instead. Just use a regular for..in or `.forEach` instead on the object keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you are:

```
this.setState(prevState => {
    return {
        content: {
            ...prevState.content,
            text: Object.keys(prevState.content.text).reduce((newTexts, key) => {
                return {
                    ...newTexts,
                    [key]: {
                        line: "changed text"
                    }
                }
            }, {})
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You should you `setState` with a function so you don't change `state` directly.

```
this.setState(prevState => {        
    for(let k in prevState.content.text){
        prevState.content.text[k].line = "changed";
    } 
    return {content: prevState.content}
}
```

## Edit:

I'm not sure if changing `prevState` directly is a good thing (please some one correct me), but you can also do

```
this.setState(prevState => {   
    let changedState = {...prevState}     
    for(let k in changedState.content.text){
        changedState.content.text[k].line = "changed";
    } 
    return {content: changedState.content}
}
```

## Edit:

As said in the comments, `{...prevState}` is going to be a shallow copy and it  can still change the state directly. One solution to this is use [lodash cloneDeep](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#cloneDeep)

Comment: `{...prevState} ` won't solve the problem, because it's a shallow copy.

Answer (score 0):

I think using `for..in` will be better.

```js
const state = {
    content: {
        text: {
            tag1: {
                line: "data1"
            },
            tag2: {
                line: "data2"
            }
        }
    }
}

for(let k in state.content.text){
  state.content.text[k].line = "changed";
} 
console.log(state)
```

Comment: This isn't a good answer because in react, you shouldn't change state directly, you should use `setState`

Comment: In the context of react state this answer makes no sense because you are mutating the state.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think [`Array#prototype#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) would be a fit.

You can use a plain modern `for...of` loop with [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) and do this:

```js
const state = {
    content: {
        text: {
            tag1: {
                line: "data1"
            },
            tag2: {
                line: "data2"
            }
        }
    }
};

for (const obj of Object.entries(state.content.text)) {
 obj[1].line = 'Changed text';
}

console.log(state);
```

---

For acheiving an immutable state you can do [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) before mutating the new object's properties.

```js
const state = {
  content: {
    text: {
      tag1: {
        line: "data1"
      },
      tag2: {
        line: "data2"
      }
    }
  }
};

// Create a new object from an existing object
const newState = Object.assign(state, {});

Object.entries(newState.content.text).forEach(x => {
  x[1].line = 'Changed text';
});

console.log(newState);
```

Comment: This isn't a good answer because in react, you shouldn't change state directly, you should use `setState`

Comment: You aren't using react's `setState`. Your answer is correct in the logic, but wrong because it isn't in the context of react