# Is it ok to change prevState directly in react setState?

Tags: reactjs

I was answering [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56078014/how-to-use-reduce-function-in-a-nested-state-object-in-reactjs/56078225#56078225) question and I came with an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56078225/9119186) that I'm not sure if it's correct or not.

Is it ok to change the `prevState` directly?

e.g.

```
this.setState(prevState => {        
    for(let k in prevState.content.text){
        prevState.content.text[k].line = "changed";
    } 
    return {content: prevState.content}
}
```

Is this acceptable? How can I do this in the correct way?

```
this.setState(prevState => {   
    let changedState = {...prevState}     
    for(let k in changedState.content.text){
        changedState.content.text[k].line = "changed";
    } 
    return {content: changedState.content}
}
```

Should I do this? Or is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: I’m not a React dev, but shouldn’t you be returning `changedState`, instead of making another object that exactly the same structure as `changedState`? It feels like if you ever added more keys to your state, you’d be removing them with that line, instead of just leaving everything other than `content` the same as it was.

Comment: @Nate I made an [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/x2qn5xxrpq) for you to see that you don't need to do that. In react you can only return an object with the properties you changed and it will update only the properties you have in that object. In normal js, it looks like you are getting rid of the other properties, but in react that wont happen.

Comment: actually Adnrii Golubenko has already answered you on this code. but I want to propose you to consider using nested component each having flat state rather just one. it'd be easier to meet single responsibility principle so components would be easier to write/maintain

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second method is also incorrect. Because spread attributes (e.g. `{...prevState}`) is not a deep copy. If you compare `prevState.content === changedState.content` you will get `true`. That's why the first and second methods are wrong. You can update state like that:

```
this.setState(prevState => {
    const newText = {};

    Object.keys(prevState.content.text).forEach((key) => {
       newText[key] = {
           ...prevState.content.text[key],
           line: "changed"
       }
    });

    return {
        content: {
            ...prevState.content,
            text: newText
        }
    }
});
```

Or you could use `reduce` instead of `forEach`.

Comment: This is an good answer, but what I found that is better is to use `lodash` `cloneDeep`.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the `prevState` but then you'll not be able to track the changes in your `componentDidUpdate` hook, because there you'll be getting the same object in the second argument as the current state, instead of the previous state.

The second method is correct